# Downloaded Pandas, but getting error when importing into Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I downloaded the pandas package to my computer using the pip install. When I try to `import pandas as pd` into Pycharm I get the following error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I know I have downloaded the package, but how do I get Pycharm to recognize that I have downloaded the package?

Comment: How did you download it exactly?

Comment: In PyCharm, when you create a new project, you can select an option to create a new virtual environment and not to use system environment. I assume that you installed "pandas" into the system environment. If so,  in newly created virtual environment you will need to also install "pandas" library. Maybe this is the case

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly don't have your interpreter set correctly.
Go to `preferences` -> `project` -> `project interpreter` and make sure that the version of Python matches the environment where you did you `pip install` or `conda install`.
Also, if you aren't sure which Python you're using you can always run `which python`.